# Is there a way to locate AND remove the odd rows, of grouped IDs within R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset containing 10,555 rows. Within this dataset I have numerous grouped IDs. I am only wanting an even number of grouped IDs, while retaining the first row of the first group.

Is there a way to locate and remove all the last odd rows within each group of IDs?
Furthermore, is there a way to group all of these odd rows that were removed?

I have tried this:

data <- sample_row_removal
toDelete <- seq(0, length(dat), 2)

I am not getting the desired result.

Sample dataset:

```
                    ID                       TIME

                    AAA                      12/18/2019 1:37:12 AM 
                    AAA                      12/18/2019 1:37:13 AM
                    AAA                      12/18/2019 1:37:14 AM
                    BBB                      12/18/2019 1:37:16 AM
                    BBB                      12/18/2019 1:37:17 AM
                    BBB                      12/18/2019 1:37:19 AM
```

Desired Outcome:

```
                    ID                       TIME

                    AAA                      12/18/2019 1:37:12 AM 
                    AAA                      12/18/2019 1:37:13 AM
                    BBB                      12/18/2019 1:37:16 AM
                    BBB                      12/18/2019 1:37:17 AM
```

removed odd rows:
                         AAA                      12/18/2019 1:37:14 AM
                         BBB                      12/18/2019 1:37:19 AM

Any assistance would be helpful. I am still researching this. Thank you

Comment: Here, you are removing the last row per each ID? `data %>%
      group_by(ID) %>%
      slice(-n())`

Comment: How do you define odd?  For me, the row numbers 1, 3, 5, ... are odd for each 'ID', but in your expected you are not removing the 1st

Comment: Yes, you are correct. My apologies. I am wondering if it is possible within R to locate and remove the last odd row within each grouped ID. I am calculating time durations, I would like to retain the very first value. The last odd rows that are discarded will be included in the calculation in a later analysis.

Comment: In that case, my solution posted should work

Comment: Yes I am trying this now. Thank you kindly

Comment: I am getting an error                                                                                           Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  group_by(ItemMessageID) %>%
  slice(if(n()%% 2 == 0 row_number"    I am researching this currently

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to close the `if` `slice(if(n()%% 2 == 0) row_number() else seq_len(n()-1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to keep rows for each 'ID' for even number of rows, after doing a group by, create a condition in `slice` to return the even number of rows

```
library(dplyr)
data1 <- data %>%
           group_by(ID) %>%
           slice(if(n()%% 2 == 0) row_number() else seq_len(n()-1))
```

and then to get all the remaining rows

```
anti_join(data, data1)
```

Comment: Hi, does this command locate the odd rows within this large dataset and then remove? I will try this now. Many thanks

Comment: @TanishaHudson You example and expected output seems to be confusing.  If you want to remove the odd rows, I don't understand why the first row is not removed

Comment: My apologies. I will clarify. Thank you.